# Can I delete Gmail account on Android safely without affecting my Gmail on computer?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Can I delete my Gmail account from my phone without the Gmail and Google account (with contacts, photos, etc) being deleted from my computer?

Comment: 1) You want to remove not delete. 2) Gmail and Google Account are not two different things. They are one single thing called Google Account.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to accounts and sync.
3. Click Remove account.

This will disassociate your phone with your google account. The Google account will still exist, just not on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Deleting the account from the phone only disables your phone from accessing the account. Your computer and its files will be untouched.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to delete an account on a Samsung Galaxy S6 is

1. Go into the account on gmail
2. Hit the arrow to the right of the account name to bring up a settings menu. This arrow is right above the inbox.
3. Choose **Manage Accounts**
4. Tap the google icon
5. Choose the account you want to delete. This will bring you to sync settings.
6. At the top right hit **More Option** and choose **Remove Account**. This will not affect the account other than taking it off from your phone.